# Binding an event to a generic function

Tags: c#, events

Is it possible to bind an event to a generic function such as

```
static void CommonEventHandler(object sender, params object[] values)
{
    //stuff
}
```

My reasoning behind this is, I want to use some events from Lua (with the NLua binding), which takes `object[]` in it's function calls from the C# side. If I could bind an event to a params function or similar, it would ease my integration with events to Lua.

Comment: You can use lambdas: `SomeEvent += (sender, args) => CommonEventHandler(sender, doSomethingWithArgs);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lambdas would allow that.

You would do something like this:

```cs
public class MyControl
{
    public MyControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        int myArgs = 123;
        MyButton.Click += (sender, e) => MyCustomMethod(sender, e, myArgs);

    }
    public void MyCustomMethod(object sender, EventArgs e, int myArgs)
    {

        // this prints "123" when the button is pressed
        MessageBox.Show(myArgs.ToString());
    }
}
```

Just replace `int myArgs` with the argument type and value that you wish to use.